# How can I select a particular tab using Auto Hotkey?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I have a window with custom controls with a Tab Bar Control like:

`Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 | Tab 4 | ...`

I want to select Tab 1 (or Tab N for that matter). When I activate the Window it can have the focus anywhere from Tab 1 to Tab N.

I know that there is the (in my opinion) ugly way to set the windows to a certain size and then just click the coordinates of the tab. I could also select the tab bar and then calculate the position on the x-axis. These to methods are not appropriate, since the windows layout can be configured and I want the solution to work on different computers.

Is there a more elegant way to use the *Visible Text* to select a control?

How can I select a single tab on a tab bar using Auto Hotkey or a similar program?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about ImageSearch. You could crop the images of every tab, both in active and inactive state [Background changes colour]. Then search for a specific image and use the coordinates to click. Be very careful though with cropping, one little change [e.g. background of neighbouring tabs] can make this fail.

```
;CoordMode Pixel  ; Interprets the coordinates below as relative to the     screen rather than the active window.
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 200, 200, C:\Temp\Tab1.bmp ; search for image in area staring at 0,0 to 200,200
if ErrorLevel = 2
    MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
else if ErrorLevel = 1
    MsgBox Image could not be found on the screen.
else
    SoundBeep, 1000, 1000
    MsgBox The Image was found at %FoundX% %FoundY%.
    ClickX:=FoundX + 5 ; Move the mouse click away from the edge of the icon
    ClickY:=FoundY + 5 ; Move the mouse click away from the edge of the icon
    Click, %ClickX%, %ClickY% ; Click on the Save As icon.
Return
```

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solution and if the answer was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark. This will mark the question solved. For the details see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367 Accepting Answers: How does it work?

Comment: Sorry. Was trying this today. It would work, but the target application is our main testing application and so it runs on several computers with different windows layouts. The goal is to (semi-)-automate some of the nasty little GUI tests. Anyway.. I give you one up for the idea. 
BTW: I have found a similar way to at least locate the control. Basically a text search (get all controls, get all texts of the windows and then look for the text).

Comment: Are you sure you can't access the Tab's in any other way. E.g. `Ctrl`+ `1` and `Ctrl`+ `2`...

Comment: Also, have you tried to see if you can use the AutoHotKey Windows Spy and see if the tab's can be detected under the mouse (the chance is slim, but worth a try). If they can be detected by ID that way then you're golden!

Comment: Window Spy was my first try... Unfortunatly this does not work. There is also no way to access the tab in another way. Currently I am favoring an combination of static skripts combined with a Recorded Script.